# Specific name for this style of gable roofs?

Tags: roof, roofing, architecture

How are the following sloping rooves described in architectural terminology? Notice some are bent, with a crook in the middle of the roof. Bonus points if you can tell the type of tiling on the roof.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a double roof structure or a type of Gable Roof, usually seen in regions with the tropical climate. The roofing material can be typical shingle or slate.

[image]

[image]